# scrollToRowAtIndexPath throwing error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: section (3) beyond bounds (1).'
```

I've got an array of information being displayed at my tableview, and when I hit a button I'm wanting it to scroll down to a certain cell.

Initially I thought I was getting that error because of the way I was getting my index to jump to:

```
 if let index = peopleListArray.index(where: { $0.UID == currentUser }) {
       print(index)
            let NSIndex = NSIndexPath(index: Int(index) )
            tableView.reloadData()
            print(peopleListArray.count)
            print(NSIndex)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndex as IndexPath , at: .top, animated: true )
        }
```

But then I replaced "let NSINDex... with

```
 let NSIndex = NSIndexPath(index: 1 )
```

and it's still throwing the same error.

when I'm printing out my array count and my NSIndex I'm always getting an 8 for the count (which is correct) and I'm getting 3 for the NSINdexPath which is correct.

I could understand the error if the 3 was out of bounds of my array.count but it definitely isn't.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue you are having is with the section and not with the row. Try to build the index like this:

```
NSIndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
```

Note the section is set to 0.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options that may be wrong here:

1. you passed a section that is out of bounds, i.e with index less than 0 or bigger than the specified number of sections in

   ```
    numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   ```

So just try to use 0 for the section number first.

2. the index of the row is out of bounds for the specified section (they can be different for each section)